# build android app give java.util.zip.zipexception android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following problem when try to run android studio application

```
java.util.zip.zipexception duplicate entry bo/app/a.class
```

can any one please tell me what is the problem ? in the following my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.forsale.forsale"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs=[]
            jniLibs.srcDirs=['libs']
        }
    }
}


repositories {

    jcenter()

    maven {
        url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo/'
    }

    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }

    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

    maven {
        url "http://appboy.github.io/appboy-android-sdk/sdk"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':gestureimageview')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-hipmob-2.9.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/HockeySDK-3.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.2v1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:v1.0.22'
    compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
    compile 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.2'
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-core-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-sdk-messages-2.5.jar')
    compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve it ? Please kindly let me know the reason of it, Just for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

[It](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81804)
 is not exactly same as your issue but It is sure that you got the error because of your `dependencies`. some of your `dependencies` may have `multidex` as their `dependency`.  If you have shocks in any compilation as so then try excluding that as said, Means like here, Your `compile` statement seems

```
compile 'com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.2'
```

You can change it to

```
compile('com.appboy:android-sdk-ui:1.11.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}
```

By excluding group `group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'`